# Best way to import package in other directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my directory structure,

```
dir1
    dir1f.py

dir2
    dir2f.py
    __init__.py
```

dir2f.py has a class class dir2c that I want to import inside dir1f.py so in dir1f.py I called

```
from ..dir2.dir2f import dir2c
```

but I get this error

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

As T-Heron notes, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do here, but if I had to hazard a guess I'd say you're running dir1f.py as a script (ala `python dir1/dir1f.py` or `python dir1f.py` from the `dir1` directory) which means you shouldn't use relative imports. Try:

`from dir2.dir2f import dir2c`

**Update**: If executing with `python dir1f.py`, there are a few ways to go:

1. try `python dir1/dir1f.py` from the top-level directory first; or
2. move dir2 into dir1 and run `python dir1f.py` from dir1; or
3. read up on PYTHONPATH (environment variable)

Also: have a read of PEP8, especially the imports section:

> "Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable
>   and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages)
>   if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a
>   directory inside a package ends up on sys.path)."

-- http://pep8.org/#imports

Possibly related, with quite a bit more detail: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3#16985066)

Comment: I'm executing python dir1f.py from dir1 so executing from dir2.dir2f import dir2c  produces error ImportError: No module named 'dir2'

Comment: Updated my answer -- you should be able to `from dir2.dir2f import dir2c` if `dir2/` is inside `dir1/` instead of being at the same level.